# IOS Parse Queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to parse some objects from my data base. I'm using parse.com as web service.
The following code gives me back some object based on 4 queries, 2 of them being compound.

The variable "meetingAge" must be equal to indexAge OR "6"
The variable "meetingSex" must be equal to "sex" OR "2"
The variable "isAvaiable" must be equal to YES
The variable "author" must be different from user.username

Basically i am trying to implement a query with 2 OR conditions and 2 AND conditions.

The following code gives me a wrong result, no exceptions or stuff like that, just a wrong kind of object. I'm sure it's a syntax issue but i can't figure out how to properly write this..If i just use 1 compound query and then add the 2 AND queries to that i get a right result, but then i miss 1 filter..

```
PFQuery *queryAge1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MeetingObject"];
[queryAge1 whereKey:@"meetingAge" equalTo:indexAge ];
PFQuery *queryAge2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MeetingObject"];
[queryAge2 whereKey:@"meetingAge" equalTo:@"6"];
PFQuery *queryCompound = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryAge1,queryAge2]];

PFQuery *querySex1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MeetingObject"];
[querySex1 whereKey:@"meetingSex" equalTo:user[@"sex"]];
PFQuery *querySex2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MeetingObject"];
[querySex2 whereKey:@"meetingSex" equalTo:@"2"];
queryCompound = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[querySex1,querySex2]];

[queryCompound whereKey:@"isAvaiable" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[queryCompound whereKey:@"author" notEqualTo:user.username];


[queryCompound findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
}
```

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions. Just edit your question to bump it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line... `queryCompound = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[querySex1,querySex2]];` you are creating a brand new query ignoring all the age stuff.

**EDIT**

You are overcomplicating this.

You can do this this way...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MeetingObject"];
[query whereKey:@"meetingAge" containedIn:@[@"6", indexAge]];
[query whereKey:@"meetingSex" containedIn:@[@"2", user[@"sex"]]];
[query whereKey:@"isAvaiable" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[query whereKey:@"author" notEqualTo:user.username];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
}
```

This will catch all the options you are looking for.

Also, just as a quick note. Choose your variable names to make them more readable. If they all begin with the word `query` it's hard to distinguish them. Also make them descriptive. `queryAge1` and `queryAge2` makes it harder to understand what they are doing.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't know editing a question would also bump it and ,to be honest, this website is not so user friendly...You code works! Thank you very much,  I was struggling with this for 3 days..

Comment: @Diego you'll get used to it after a while. No worries about the duplicate though. Didn't know you were so new.